# get request context in Advanced custom template tags

Tags: django, django-templates, internationalization

In Django simple and inclusion template tags allow getting the request context with

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
```

Official documentation for [custom template tags - inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

However, for custom tags, I don't see how this is done.

What I am trying to do is extend the i18n `{% trans %}` tag, to look for translation in the database first, before using `gettext`. I need access to the `request.Language` from the custom template tag.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Django doc of custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags), it's also possible to add **`takes_context`** for customs tags

```
import datetime
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def current_time(context, format_string):

    #use "context" variable here
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format_string)
```

I'm not sure how to override the existing tag at this particular scenario :( 
Anyway, what I'm suggesting is, create a `simple_tag` that takes the context and do your logic inside the  tag and return the translation text from DB. If it's not in DB, return a boolean `False`. Now in template, check these thing using `if` tag.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def is_db_available(context):
    # access your context here and do the DB check and return the translation text or 'False'
    if translation_found_in_DB:
        return "Some translation text"
    return False
```

and in template

```
{% load custom_tags %}
{% load i18n %}
{% is_db_available as check %} 
{% if check %}  <!-- The if condition  -->
    {{ check }}
{% else %}
    {% trans "This is the title." %} <!-- Calling default trans tag  -->
{% endif %}
```

Comment: this won't work, you are using the wrong parameters for the tag function, it can take two parameters (context,string) and not 3 (content,parser,token)
in fact error raised is "did not receive value(s) for the argument(s): 'token'"

Comment: @uri.lazar Yeah. That's right. Now I've updated the answer. Please do check and try it

Comment: @uri.lazar did you try?